# Unhandled exception at 0x0FD98EF2 (opencv_imgproc248d.dll) in LearningMachine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: opencv

This is the code I'm using:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\private\\MachinLearning";

boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(path);
Mat imgIter;

for (; iterator != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++iterator)
{
    string file_name = path;
    file_name.append(iterator->path().filename().string());
    imgIter = cv::imread(file_name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat scalled_img(75, 135, imgIter.type(), cv::Scalar(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    cv::resize(imgIter, scalled_img, scalled_img.size());

}
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try checking that `imgIter` isn't empty at each iteration.

Comment: Do you know how to debug line by line?